# Change url from HTTPS to HTTP javascript when leaving page

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, ssl

I currently change an individual page to be secure if location.procotcol isn't https:

```
 if (location.protocol != "https:")
 {
   location.replace("https://" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname);
 }
```

This works but when I leave the page my protocol is still https and I would like this to be http.

I've tried the below which triggers when I leave the page but it doesn't seem to make a difference with the protocol

```
$(window).unload(function() {
location.replace("http://" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname);
});
```

Is it possible for me to change the protocol to be http when leaving the page but with the functionality coming from the page that is being left.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the location when the user leaves the page. That would be utterly annoying and easily exploited by spammers.

Comment: I don't think you read my question properly.  I don't want to change the location. I want to change the protocol.

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer properly. You want to change the location, even if it's a small part of it.